# mysql не обязательный параметры в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите пожалуйста. Есть форма на сайте, пользователь указывает гендер человека и город проживания, но город не обязательный к заполнению. Если город не указали,  то выбираются все города.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender=:gender and from_city=:search_city`

Сейчас этот запрос работает только если город указать, интересует запрос sql, а не собирание запроса почестям из переменных PHP, тк это PDO и мне нужно использовать все переменные в запросе, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Ты можешь точно так же собитать и параметры собирать по частям

Comment: @Miron потому что пользователь может его указать?

Comment: @Ипатьев Тогда всегда можно написать вместо нужного города `from_city`. Выберутся из всех городов

Comment: @Miron нельзя вписать, это же имя поля, а не строка

Comment: @Ипатьев Почему нельзя? Работает же. Думаю, что даже медленней не будет - sql же не тупой

Comment: @Miron потому что запрос from_city='from_city' не найдет ни одного города

Comment: `WHERE from_city=COALESCE(:search_city, from_city)` - при отсутствии передавать NULL (но это "привет индексам") или `WHERE from_city=:search_city OR :search_city IS NULL)` (но параметр надо передавать два раза.)

Comment: @Ипатьев а зачем в шаблоне в кавычки заключать? Так вы себя ограничиваете. Запрос from_city = from_city выполнится удачно

Comment: @Miron потому что по-другому не работает. Почитайте что-нибудь про подготовленные выражения и что означает запись `from_city=:search_city`

Comment: @Ипатьев Почитал. На джаве, кстати, это дело провернуть довольно легко с помощью MessageFormat(на место `{n}` ставится значение n-ого аргумента). Почему нельзя заменить `:search_city` на `'New York'`, если передали город, и на `from_city`, если не передали?

Comment: @Miron потому что это уже не будет иметь смысла. Если уж лезть руками в запрос, то проще вообще не добавлять условие, чем городить забор из if - else.

Comment: @Ипатьев Собирание запроса по частям - бОльший забор. if-else можно заменить тернарными операторами(если они есть в php, конечно). Хотя, несомненно, ваш подход выглядит более основательно

Comment: @Miron если честно то я уже немного устал от этой беседы. Заменить тернарным оператором нельзя, поскольку в случае не пустого значения надо еще добавить элемент в массив с параметрами.

Answer (score 2):

Собирание запроса по частям - это самый распространённый способ решения этой задачи. Параметры точно так же можно собирать по частям и добавлять в массив, который можно будет потом разом передать в execute(), благо PDO продоставляет нам эту замечательную возможность.

[Пример сборки запроса и параметров по частям](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where):

```
$conditions = []; // части запроса
$parameters = []; // параметры

// проверка входящих переменных
if (!empty($_GET['name']))
{
    // пример с LIKE
    $conditions[] = 'name LIKE ?';
    $parameters[] = '%'.$_GET['name']."%";
}

if (!empty($_GET['sex']))
{
    // пример с точным совпадением
    $conditions[] = 'sex = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_GET['sex'];
}

if (!empty($_GET['car']))
{

    // пример с несовпадением
    $conditions[] = 'car != ?';
    $parameters[] = $_GET['car'];
}

if (!empty($_GET['date_start']) && $_GET['date_end'])
{

    // BETWEEN
    $conditions[] = 'date BETWEEN ? AND ?';
    $parameters[] = $_GET['date_start'];
    $parameters[] = $_GET['date_end'];
}

// основной запрос
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

// проверка, есть ли у нас хоть одно условие
if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

// обычный процесс prepare/execute/fetch
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($parameters);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

соответственно для именованных параметров надо писать не `?`, а `:name` и не `$parameters[] = $_GET['name']`, а `$parameters['name'] = $_GET['name']`.

> интересует запрос sql, а не собирание запроса по частям

В принципе это возможно, но выглядит как извращение. Реализацию можешь посмотреть по ссылке выше

Comment: Благодарю, очень развернуто, сейчас буду ознакамливаться!

Comment: соответственно для именованных параметров надо писать не ?, а :name и не $parameters[] = $_GET['name'], а $parameters['name'] = $_GET['name']